# python using requests and a webpage with a login issue

Tags: python-3.x, authentication, python-requests, trading

I'm trying to login to a website via python to print the info. So I don't have to keep logging into multiple accounts.

In the tutorial I followed, he just had a login and password, but this one has

Website Form Data
[image]

Does the _wp attributes change each login?

The code I use:

```
mffloginurl = ('https://myforexfunds.com/login-signup/')
mffsecureurl = ('https://myforexfunds.com/account-2')

payload = {
    'log': '*****@gmail.com',
    'pdw': '*****'
    '''brandnestor_action':'login',
    '_wpnonce': '9d1753c0b6',
    '_wp_http_referer': '/login-signup/',
    '_wpnonce': '9d1753c0b6',
    '_wp_http_referer': '/login-signup/'''


}

r = requests.post(mffloginurl, data=payload)
print(r.text)
```

using the correct details of course, but it doesn't login.

I tried without the extra wordpress elements and also with them but it still just goes to the signin page.

python output
[image]

different site addresses, different login details

Comment: `nonce` is usually a value which changes with every request.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah the nonce will change with every new visit to the page.

I would use `request.session()` so that it automatically stores session cookies and all that good stuff.

Do a session.GET('some_login_page.com')

Parse with the response content with BeautifulSoup to retrieve the nonce.

Then add that into the payload of your POST request when you login.

### A very quick and dirty example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

email = 'test@email.com'
password = 'password1234'
url = 'https://myforexfunds.com/account-2/'

# Start a session
with requests.session() as session:
    # Send a GET request to the login page
    r = session.get(url)
    
    # Check if the request was successful
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print("Get Request Failed")
        
    # Parse the HTML content of the page
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    
    # Extract the value of the nonce from the HTML
    nonce = soup.find(id='woocommerce-login-nonce')['value']
    
    # Set up the login form data
    params ={
    "username": email,
    "password": password,
    "woocommerce-login-nonce": nonce,
    "_wp_http_referer": "/account-2/",
    "login": "Log+in"
    }

    # Send a POST request with the login form data
    r = session.post(url, params=params)
    
    # Check if the request was successful
    if r.status_code != 200:
        print("Login Failed")
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for your help! That makes alot of sense...